# Django autocomplete light POSTs 4 times when creating new choices in the autocomplete form

Tags: django, python-3.x, autocomplete, django-autocomplete-light

I've created this model:

```
class TitleDescriptionLazyModel(models.Model):

class Meta:
    abstract = True

title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
description = models.TextField(blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title

class Jobsite(TitleDescriptionLazyModel):
    pass
```

Which is used in this autocomplete view as described in the documentation (views.py):

```
class JobsiteAutocomplete(LoginRequiredMixin, autocomplete.Select2QuerySetView):

def get_queryset(self):
    if not self.request.user.is_authenticated():
        return Jobsite.objects.none()

    qs = Jobsite.objects.all()

    if self.q:
        qs = qs.filter(title__istartswith=self.q)

    return qs
```

and my urls.py have the title field set as the "create_field":

```
urlpatterns = [
    JobsiteAutocomplete.as_view(create_field='title'), name='jobsite_autocomplete'),
]
```

But when I run it I get the autocomplete view passing the get requests until I click on the create button at which point it POSTs 4 times creating 4 new items in the database when I expect it to create 1:

```
> [22/Aug/2016 20:44:04] "GET /worklogs/jobsite-autocomplete/ HTTP/1.1" 200 356
[22/Aug/2016 20:44:10] "GET /worklogs/jobsite-autocomplete/?q=som HTTP/1.1" 200 252
[22/Aug/2016 20:44:11] "GET /worklogs/jobsite-autocomplete/?q=some HTTP/1.1" 200 254
[22/Aug/2016 20:44:12] "GET /worklogs/jobsite-autocomplete/?q=somewhere HTTP/1.1" 200 116
[22/Aug/2016 20:44:13] "POST /worklogs/jobsite-autocomplete/ HTTP/1.1" 200 31
[22/Aug/2016 20:44:13] "POST /worklogs/jobsite-autocomplete/ HTTP/1.1" 200 31
[22/Aug/2016 20:44:13] "POST /worklogs/jobsite-autocomplete/ HTTP/1.1" 200 31
[22/Aug/2016 20:44:13] "POST /worklogs/jobsite-autocomplete/ HTTP/1.1" 200 31
```

[image: it creates 4 every time... why?]

django = 1.9
python = 3.4
django-autocomplete-light (3.1.8)

Answer (score 0):

I was using jQuery v1.11.3

I upgraded to jQuery 2.2.4 and it worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is also answered in the issues.
https://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light/issues/758#issuecomment-329814124

It happens when you have more than one select2.js in your page.

In my case, i was using crispy forms and i also had {{ form.media }} on the page i removed the variable {{ form.media }} it worked good